# why it is showing two pictures of a picture

Tags: picture-samples

I have got a picture of CIMSS satellite and it is peculiarly showing two pictures continuously I am new on this picture effects

May I know is this any kind of effect given into it.

any help will be really appreciable

why it is showing two pictures of a picture

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with photography.

Comment: what...it is not related to photography?

Comment: Do you mean "what is an animated GIF?"

Comment: This is a file-format question and could be done with anything. It certainly does not come from a camera like that.

Comment: I do not think it is only for gif I can prove it on png also something was happen on taking the photo from CIMSS

Comment: oh my god negative vote again

Comment: -1 Please prove that it is not a gif, or that it happened "on taking the photo from CIMSS".

Comment: Forget the negative votes. They won't hurt you. Some of the people here are more insensitive than others. They tend toward negativity to point out shortcomings in what they expect according to a subjective view. They forget that there was once a time when they were ignorant. They conquered their ignorance and sacrificed their sensitivity and tolerance (if they had some to begin with) for their sense of ego and superiority. There are some mistakes made by everyone. Try to remain positive in spite of them. I'm sure they mean well. They're mean, anyway.

Comment: When you did your screen-grab, you copied an "animated gif" with several layers that show a sequence. You'll have to edit out the extra gif layers to get the one you want. Search for gif editing to find out more. Good luck and chin-up.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [.GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/graphics_interchange_format) ([**G**raphics **I**nterchange **F**ormat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/graphics_interchange_format)) image. This format allows the creator to have the images swap (although this only happens on preset time intervals). This format is one of the formats commonly used on the internet, especially for animations.

Answer (score 3):

This is a GIF file.  A feature of GIF is that it can have multiple images stored within it and it will rotate through them.  It was originally developed by Compuserve to allow for images to be loaded across types of computers which formerly didn't have common image formats (thus the interchange in the name).  Interchange does not related to the fact it can animate the image, but in a time before video files could be transferred between system types and when video was too big to transfer over the Internet, it was a nice feature to be able to show basic animation.

As bandwidth increased and common formats like JPEG and MPEG were formed, it went mostly out of style, but still hangs around occasionally, primarily for the animated image sequence feature since it is smaller and easier than video.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the reason for "interchange", I have updated my answer slightly.

Comment: @damnedtruths - no problem, if you had had that part, I wouldn't have bothered with my answer, but figured some background was in order beyond simply a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but the B+W image looks like near infrared and the color image is apparently some other sensor data colorized to make the small variations more noticable to humans.  The colored image might be something like sea height from nominal, which is usually correlated pretty well to surface pressure.

Comment: thank you....but it is always toggle ...

Comment: I think its real IR, not NIR. The colour version is the 11 micrometer band, and the other is maybe 3um, which is close to the one thermal cameras use (1.3um).

Comment: dammit! they call 0.7um (700nm, reddish-nir) the day/night band haha

Comment: The B&W was shot at around 5h34Z, around 1h34 local time. You can see the city lights still glowing. DR[?] looks like it's having a party!